# Setting up a intrusion system

Tags: security

I am trying to set up a intrusion system for 12.04 LTS and was pointed in the direction of using PAM to do so. How can I setup PAM and is there any other intrusion system out there for ubuntu?

Comment: Are you talking about "intrusion detection systems? Could you please tell me, what PAM is, as I'm very interested in this topic, too.

Comment: Yes I am talking about "intrusion detection systems"! well PAM is Linux Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) provide dynamic authorization for applications and services in a Linux system. Linux PAM is evolved from the Unix Pluggable Authentication Modules architecture.

Comment: If you are talking about an IDS, PAM is not an IDS. PAM is for authentication. IDS is concerned with identifying network-based attacks. If this is what you are looking for then I would suggest Snort.

Answer (score 0):

I think Snort is what your looking for.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SnortIDS